# Error USING NESTED FOR condition

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I need to use nested loop in my stored procedure. (Conditions inside condition). I have been working on this from several days. My actual code is very long, however i have pasted the code that gave ERROR. Please help me debug this code. What could be the error in this nested FOR condition

```
  if @commissiontypee!=@commissiontypee1 or @commissionamountt!=@commissionamountt1
        (
            begin
                if exists (select debit from tblledger where passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (typenumber=2 or typenumber=3)
                    (
                        begin
                        update tblledger set debit=@commissionamountt, typenumber=@typenumberr where ( passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (TypeNumber='2' or TypeNumber='3'))
                        set @initialdate= (select top(1) datetimer from tblledger where passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (typenumber=2 or typenumber=3))
                        set @datedifferences=datediff(day,@initialdate,getdate())
                            if @commissiontypee!=@commissiontypee1
                            (
                                begin
                                insert into tbllogfiles (OnDate,What,OfPassportnumber,ToValue,ChangedFrom,aftertime)values(getdate(),'Commission and ""COMMISSION-TYPE"" changed',@passportnumberr,@commissionamountt,commissionamount,@datedifferences)    
                                end
                            else
                                begin
                                insert into tbllogfiles (OnDate,What,OfPassportnumber,ToValue,ChangedFrom,aftertime)values(getdate(),'Commission changed',@passportnumberr,@commissionamountt,commissionamount,@datedifferences)    
                                end
                            )
                        )
                    else
                        (
                        begin 
                            if @commissiontype=0
                            --condition
                            insert into tblledger (passportnumber,datetimer, typenumber,debit) values (@passportnumberr,getdate(),2,@commissionamountt)
                            else
                            --condition
                            insert into tblledger (passportnumber,datetimer, typenumber,debit) values (@passportnumberr,getdate(),2,@commissionamountt)
                        end
                        )

            end
        )
```

Error :: incorrect syntax near BEGIN

Comment: Where did you find that ( and ) where needed with the IF statement?

Comment: I thought that ( and ) would make it more simplier.. Using ELSE statement would create confusion about 'WHICH IF CONDITION it belongs to'

Comment: Syntax parsers are strict. The TSQL parser doesn't allow you to add that syntactic sugar/noise hence your syntax error.

Comment: The logical condition i have used in the above CODE is necessary for me.. I am writing a program and the above logic are essential for that program...
HOW can i execute above logical condition? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
if @commissiontypee!=@commissiontypee1 or @commissionamountt!=@commissionamountt1
begin
    if exists (select debit from tblledger where passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (typenumber=2 or typenumber=3))
    begin
        update tblledger set debit=@commissionamountt, typenumber=@typenumberr where ( passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (TypeNumber='2' or TypeNumber='3'))
        set @initialdate= (select top(1) datetimer from tblledger where passportnumber=@passportnumberr and (typenumber=2 or typenumber=3))
        set @datedifferences=datediff(day,@initialdate,getdate())
            if @commissiontypee!=@commissiontypee1
            begin
                insert into tbllogfiles (OnDate,What,OfPassportnumber,ToValue,ChangedFrom,aftertime)values(getdate(),'Commission and ""COMMISSION-TYPE"" changed',@passportnumberr,@commissionamountt,commissionamount,@datedifferences)    
            end
            else
            begin
                insert into tbllogfiles (OnDate,What,OfPassportnumber,ToValue,ChangedFrom,aftertime)values(getdate(),'Commission changed',@passportnumberr,@commissionamountt,commissionamount,@datedifferences)    
            end

    End
    else
    begin 
        if @commissiontype=0
        --condition
        insert into tblledger (passportnumber,datetimer, typenumber,debit) values (@passportnumberr,getdate(),2,@commissionamountt)
        else
        --condition
        insert into tblledger (passportnumber,datetimer, typenumber,debit) values (@passportnumberr,getdate(),2,@commissionamountt)
    end
end
```

Comment: i got solution to this program.